# Is it possible to login with google account and save their information to DB

Tags: php, google-signin

I wonder is there any way to add google account information into my database as the user sign-in into google account, it's possible when you use G+ api but is it possible when I don't want to use G+ API and just want to integrate google sign-in. 
Any help from you people??
Thanks :)

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
};
```

Comment: you checked google docs and nothing great? how else do you think you can achieve this?

Comment: by the help google docs I am able to integrate it but I want that console logged info into my database. I wonder where should I do my insert code so that i could add it into my DB it's available but it's for G+ not for google integration.

Comment: I think you have console logged all the info you need. Now you want to save this data to database. Am I right?

Comment: yes exactly, by following google docs footstep I have done this much. no I need that to store into my DB so that user need to get registered again in my site.

Comment: If you are using javascript, you have to send the data to your server via submitting a form/ajax.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
<script>
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
    console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
    console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
    console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

    // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
    var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
    console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
    //You have your data in the variable `id_token`. Now send this to your server to be stored
};
```

The code you are writing is in javascript. Now you need to communicate with your server to send data on your browser (residing in the javascript variable) to the server.

You have different options
1. Set the data to a form and submit it
2. set the data to a query string and redirect
3. send data to the server via ajax.

and on the server, you need to receive data and write to database using any of the languages like php, java, c# etc.

Comment: I would suggest you to learn technologies and programming languages and differentiate between front end technologies and back end/server technologies to be a good programmer and not just copy pasting. I know everybody start by doing copy paste